# PHP execute command after executing node in PHP

Tags: php, ssh

I want to execute a second command after executing the first but it's not working for me... This is the code I have

```
<?php
include('Net/SSH2.php');
$owed = $_POST["value"];
$server = "127.0.0.1";
$username = "xxx";
$password = "xxx";
$command1 = "cd /var/www/ww && node bot.js";

$ssh = new Net_SSH2($server);
if (!$ssh->login($username, $password)) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}
echo $ssh->exec($command1);
```

This is all fine and its working till this step, BUT.. the problem is after executing the NODE is asking for VALUE to proceed the task, im getting the value on the first index of the script but i dont know how to execute it after the first command.

[image: picture]

// edit

I need to pass $_POST["value"] as a second command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [documentation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/documentation/net.html) says you can use `write` in this case

> 5.1.4. read() / write() vs. exec()
>
> write() sends input - such as a command - to the server. Normally,
>   operating systems don't process commands until the Enter key is hit,
>   so to mimic this, you'll need to send a "\n", a "\r\n" or a "\r"
>   depending on the operating system the server you're connecting to is
>   using. Note that although the input will most likely be a command it
>   doesn't have to be.
>
> What you send will be parsed by whatever is
>   expecting user-entered text. So if you type in "passwd\n" the input -
>   until "\n" is entered - will be parsed by passwd as a new or existing
>   password - not as a command to be ran by the shell

**so you probably want something like this:**

```
<?php

    include('Net/SSH2.php');
    $owed = $_POST["value"];
    $server = "127.0.0.1";
    $username = "xxx";
    $password = "xxx";

    $ssh = new Net_SSH2($server);
    if (!$ssh->login($username, $password)) {
        exit('Login Failed');
    }

    echo $ssh->exec('cd /var/www/www');
    echo $ssh->exec('node bot.js');
    echo $ssh->write($owed);
```

Comment: I think this is the right thing i need. but im getting error.. sorry im kinda newbie trying to make something out of nothing

http://pastebin.com/fwKiHRgK

im under CentOS 6.7

Btw, thanks!